# jQuery error in MVC project: Datepicker is not a function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

This is what is in my view:

```
@Html.TextBox("toDateFilter", "", new { @class = "datepicker" })
...etc
...etc


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

I am getting the error:

> Datepicker is not a function.

I have followed the advice of all the other similar questions, and nothing has worked. I also changed the View to these imports instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" />
```

I also tried this instead:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

Also I did check that the jquery-ui.min.js file loaded correctly.

Any ideas why this is going wrong? Let me know if I can supply more info...

Comment: Suggests to me that your `.ready()` is running before the jquery-ui.min script has loaded. Can you put a breakpoint on that line and see if the external script has loaded at point?

Comment: use `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js`. using https instead of http worked for me. give it a whirl.

Comment: Your code should work fine.  I just copied and pasted it from your question and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Starscream1984 I added: `if(typeof jQuery.ui !== 'undefined'){alert("Test")}` which worked so it has definitely loaded.

Comment: @user1 Tried https, but it still did not work...

Comment: @AlanSchapira - at what point in the code does it run that test?

Comment: it works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/u52pvn3j/

Comment: @Starscream1984 When u asked, I had run the alert outside of the ready() function. So I ran it inside the ready() function and the alert didn't show up. So i removed the ready() function completely and the datepicker worked. Thank you! But any idea why the ready() function was running before the jquery-ui.min script had loaded?

Comment: External Links are loaded asynchronously, So if you have minimal UI elements, there are chances that the DOM will be ready before the javascript is loaded. It could also depend on the server you are calling for the javascript like code.jquery may be running slow, so it serves files slower. Also your own internet connection could be a factor.

Comment: Why arnt you including your scripts in the HEAD?

Comment: I would make sure external scripts are in the `<head>` and also maybe look into having the scripts load from your own domain, rather than CDN. It should then be safe to expect that `ready()` will run when all dependencies have loaded

Comment: @Starscream1984 I have added `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js")` to my _Layout file, so it is from my own domain, plus it is in the `<head>`, but the `ready()` function still throws the same error if I include that function...

Comment: Hard to say without being able to debug it myself, but maybe you could try using `$(window).load( function(){...} );` instead of the `.ready()`, it runs a bit later in the page loading cycle apparently

Comment: @Starscream1984 It didn't like that either but thanks for the try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer from Starscream1984 in the comments, so props to them!

The issue is that the `ready()` function was being called before the `jquery-ui.js` script had finished loading.

This could not be fixed by moving it into the `<head>` nor loading the scripts from my own domain.

I was able to fix it simply by removing the `ready()` function entirely, and just running the contents.

If anyone knows how I can force the script to load first, or the `ready()` function to be called last, please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

Datepicker is not a function. i am also facing this issue.i have resolved it  using Jquery Noconflict function.

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $('.datefield').datepicker();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#nameOfTheFieldInModel").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

In document ready?

Comment: If `datepicker()` is not a function, it doesn't matter what you try to pass in to it.

Comment: @AlanSchapira you could try moving the jquery inclusion in the Site.Master